# How do I get Windows10 to run my Python script using CMD? I Keep getting this [errono 2]

Tags: python, windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNisJ.png)How do I get Python to run my script? I Keep getting this error. My code is basic print ('hello world') written in Notepad ++. I can get it to work without manually typing the path in the command prompt. Looking at the picture, it looks like python is looking for the file in the another location. I checked the path environment variable and everything looks good. I looked online but can't find any solution specific to this problem. Why is it doing that? Please help, I am new to this.

Comment: What is the error? Where are you executing the script from?

Comment: this is the error i am getting C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\emman\new1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
In particular, off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: `No such file or directory` is a hint as to what went wrong. If you're ever wondering why something isn't working try looking errors up to understand why it's happening and what the solution could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of these to run your code in cmd

```
py yourscript.py
```

Or

```
python yourscript.py
```

Or

```
py3 yourscript.py
```

Or

```
python3 yourscript.py
```

If you have to install modules use

```
python -m pip install module_name
```

This is very basic thing but could be really annoying if you are completely new so good luck

Comment: yeah its frustrating to be honest. i still get the same error when i run the command C:\Users\emman>python new1.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\emman\new1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @S_Dinho type ‘dir’ to see all the files in current location

Comment: Apparently python file is not in sam directory

Comment: the location is C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python Projects\file_name.py

Comment: @S_Dinho try cd C:\users\emman\Desktop\python projects

Comment: After that run file_name.py

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thanks a lot. Why is that tho? why wouldn't it work with just "Python file_name.py". So every time i want to run the script i have to write the whole path?

Comment: You were not in same directory as of python file.. here are some tips about using windows cmd and how to nevigate https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands

Answer (score 1):

You can directly run this example in CMD:

```
python C:\Users\saeed\desktop\python-projects\test.py
```

You can run script with `absolute` path of the script. I think you're trying relative path and it may not be correct in your case.

Comment: This is the error i am getting C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\emman\new1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure the file is in `C:\Users\emman\`? Copy this path in your file explorer and see if your file exists there. Where is your file exactly? Is it in Desktop? In any directories or sub-directory? Let me know where exactly it is.

Comment: its in the desktop. C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python Projects\file_name.py

Comment: So you should run `python C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python Projects\file_name.py` exactly. Did you try that?

Comment: Yeah I did but same error. C:\Users\emman>python C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python Projects\new1.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You can `cd` to `Python Projects`, which is `"cd C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python Projects\"` (note the " in cd) and then run `python file_name.py`, or use `python "C:\Users\emman\Desktop\Python Projects\file_name.py"` to avoid any misunderstanding of `space` character in folder name. It should work I think.